# Price table collapsible

Tags: html, wordpress

We are looking for a price table that is collapsible. Let's say if we have 5 options in our price table, I want 3 options collapsed. When you press on an option, it opens. So it's not the whole table I want to be collapsible, just a part of the table. We are looking for a way to do this, but we haven't found the solution yet.

How can we make this work and is it even possible? After spending some time on Google we couldn't find a direct answer to this matter.

Is there a plugin or some kind of code we can use for this?

Comment: Per SO guidelines, this question is off topic: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ty3b/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! this is something we could consider. Is there any way to make a existing price table collapsible? A price table from a plugin or something